# Update query in bulk using single query instead of using loop in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I'm looking for a query to update in bulk using single query instead of using query in loop. I have more than 2000 products and I have to update there stock value. Right now I using loop for each product so its take too much time. Here is my code

```
foreach($products as $srcProduct){ 
                $product_id = $srcProduct['product_id'];         
                $onhand = 0;
                if(isset($srcProductOnhand[$product_id])){
                        $onhand = $srcProductOnhand[$product_id];
                }
                TransferSourceProducts::where(['product_id' => $product_id, 'transfer_id' => $id])
                                       ->update(['onhand' =>$onhand]);                   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. It works fast.

```
INSERT into `table` (id, description)
VALUES (1, 'desc1'), (2, 'desc2'), (3, 'desc3')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE description = VALUES(description)
```

Hope it helps.